# Putting the variable into the a href tag

Tags: javascript

i am having issue with assigning the variable into the URL

This is the code

```
var value = i+1;

 var customPopup = 'Latitude: ' + data.Table[i].Latitude + '</br>Longitude: ' + data.Table[i].Longitude
                + '</br>Station: ' + data.Table[i].StationID + ' </br>Box: ' + data.Table[i].BoxID + '</br>Timestamp: ' + data.Table[i].LocationSend + "<br><a target='_blank' href='/Home/History?DeviceID= ' style='color: #000000'>Click Here For Location History</a></br>";
```

Comment: Aaand what is the issue?

Comment: Hi, what value are you trying to put into the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals might help (using backticks ``):

```
var value = i+1;

var customPopup = 'Latitude: ' + data.Table[i].Latitude + 
                  '<br/>Longitude: ' + data.Table[i].Longitude + 
                  '<br/>Station: ' + data.Table[i].StationID + 
                  '<br/>Box: ' + data.Table[i].BoxID + 
                  '<br/>Timestamp: ' + data.Table[i].LocationSend + 
                  `<br/><a target='_blank' href='/Home/History?DeviceID=${value}' style='color: #000000'>Click Here For Location History</a><br/>`;
```